# split information in single cell to multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this information in an a single cell

```
Please register for me: 

NAME: Zaki Bin Manjoy   
PS NUMBER: 675676
DIETARY PREFERENCE (halal/vegetarian): Halal
LOCATION: KFELS MPH KOM Tower Level 10
```

I want to split it in multiple cells to get data like name, pc number, dietary preference and location.

Comment: As a start, you need to describe what the data looks like.  What kind of variation?  What kinds of delimiters?  Is there any uniformity that parsing can be based on?

Comment: YSA, I rolled back edits by @Jeeped because it appeared that the way your example looks in the question is the actual contents of a single cell, as stated in your description, and his edits appeared to introduce structure that wasn't there.  However, looking at your raw question in the edit history, it looks like he just cleaned up formatting that was already there, which conflicts with your description.  In order for you to get a proper answer, your description and example need to match.  Is that entire example the contents of one cell or is it already parsed into separate cells?

Answer (score 1):

In an an unused cell to the right (top row perhaps), put in this formula,

`=CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A), "NAME: ","PS NUMBER:", "DIETARY PREFERENCE (halal/vegetarian):","LOCATION:")`

Fill right for a total of four cells.. That will give you the four categories that you are looking for. For this example, I'll say you put it in C1.

Directly under the cell with *NAME:* (C2 in the example) put this formula,

`=TRIM(CLEAN(MID($A1,FIND(C$1,$A1)+LEN(C$1), IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$A1,FIND(C$1,$A1)),LEN($A1))-(FIND(C$1,$A1)+LEN(C$1)))))`

Then fill right for a total of four cells. You should have something like the following.

[image: Transpose Multiline Cell Data]

With more data in column A, you just have to select C2:F2 and fill down as necessary to catch all the data in column A.